# How to create a Stored Procedure across two (2) different Databases on the same MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I embed the following command on a Stored Procedure across two (2) different Databases on the same MySQL Server?

```
Update Database1.Table1, Database2.Table2 
set Database1.Table1.df_oria = Database2.Table2.df_oria 
where Database1.Table1.dslam_code = Database2.Table2.dslam_code;
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a problem with the code you have?

Comment: Yes. I get Syntax Error writing this code inside MySQL Workbench...I write this code inside the Database1 Plain & then the System It underlines the Database2.Table2.

Comment: database2.table2 doesn't exist - you did say the 2 dbs were on the same mysql server? Can you publish the output of SHOW databases please

Comment: Yes they are on the same MySQL Server. Table1 exists only into Database1 & Table2 exists only into Database2.

Comment: ___You get a syntax error___ Could we see ALL that error message, who knows it might make a answer easier to offer

Comment: Just to confirm table2 existence please publish output of select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name = <'table2'>

Comment: Error Message after I write the procedure & then I press Apply Button: "Apply Changes to Object. The Object's DDL statement contains syntax errors. You cannot modify this object until you fix the errors."

Comment: @ P.Salmon, both tables exist since I use these tables for years now. Now I just want to transfer data between them.

Comment: I've just tried this code using mysqlworkbench wizard and it applied without error - didn't even complain about the tables not existing. I suggest you try using a create table statement or perhaps there is a lurking non printing character.